# Can't make my slice from the HTML link repeat to extend

Tags: html, outlook, templates

I have attempted to insert an html image withing an email (Outlook) to save as a template.  I am finding that there is a slice that should repeat is not working correctly (to have the color extend to where the text ends).  Is there someone who may be able to assist me in this matter?  Below is the coding that I am using.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Ticket Closure Notice</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  </HEAD>

 <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" LEFTMARGIN="0" TOPMARGIN="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0">
   <TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">
     <TR>
       <TD width="114" valign="top"><IMG SRC="http://intranet.ca.state.gov/email_templates/images/left_bar_outages_advisory.gif"></TD>
       <TD valign="top" width="100%">

         <TABLE WIDTH=100% height="100%" BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0>
           <TR>
             <TD height="128" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" background="images on server 2/top_bar_advisory_tile.gif">
               <img src="images on server 2/top_bar_advisory.gif" width="157" height="128"></TD>
           </TR>
           <TR>
             <TD height="100%" bordercolor="#FFFFFF"><br>
               <br></TD>
           </TR>
           <TR>
             <TD align="right" height="74"><br>
               <hr style="BORDER-RIGHT: gray 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: gray 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: gray 1px solid; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-BOTTOM: gray 1px solid; HEIGHT: 1px; TEXT-ALIGN: right">
               <a href="http://caweb/doweb"><img src="http://intranet.ca.state.gov/email_templates/images/CA-CST-lg.gif" width="144" height="52" border="0"></a></TD>
           </TR>
         </TABLE>

         </TD>
      </TR></TABLE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of style attributes that don't work in outlook (and other mail clients).

Here's a good guide: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/